# Can we add result page?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I made application in windows phone (Using Windows Phone SDK 7.1 /C#).
But am stuck, I had applied a button for displaying result but my page is full of contents.
So can I link this button to a seperate page which will display result(obvious that this page cannot be viewed in any ways else as my result is random and the best part in my application).
Thank you.

Comment: There is a good example of what you're trying to do in this video from TechDays 2012 in Belgium.<http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechDays/TechDays-2012-Belgium/242>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can have this is a separate page and navigate to it via the `NavigationService`. It sounds like you are struggling with how to structure your application. I would recommend reading this tutorial a wrote a little while back:

[A Simple Windows Phone 7 MVVM Tombstoning Example](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/05/a-simple-windows-phone-7-mvvm-tombstoning-example/)

It details how to navigate from page to page, and includes source code.